# How to make echo work inside 'content' of jquery,in google maps infowindow

Tags: php, jquery

i'm here with a new problem,i want to echo the variable from php inside the  content of infowindow,any suggestions?

Here is my code,Inside the infowindow content i have used some html code,that i have to replace with php variables.
for Eg:deviceid1 should be replaced with value from database

```
  var trieste = new google.maps.LatLng(45.6111555,13.8022614);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom:      12,
    center:    trieste,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map($("#map_canvas")[0], mapOptions);

  var places =
    [
      {
        "position": [45.6466883,13.7631226]
      },
      {
        "position": [45.6433281,13.7895584]
      },
      {
        "position": [45.6017884,13.6673355] 
      },
      {
        "position": [45.622442,13.7641525] 
      }
    ]

  var currentPlace = null;
  var icons=["green.png","red.png","blue.png","yellow.png"];
  var i=0;

    $(places).each(function() {
      var place = this;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(place.position[0], place.position[1],place.position[2],place.position[3]),
        map     : map,
        icon    : icons[i]
      });

   if(i==0)
   {
   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content: '<ul><li>Device ID1</li><li>Device configuration1</li><li>Device Description1</li></ul><a href="riacqua/activepanel.php">Goto RIACQUA</a>'
     }); 
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
   infowindow.open(map, marker);
     });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
   infowindow.close();
     });
    }
```

Comment: Its maybe more a PHP question when a jQuery question.

Comment: i'm a beginner in jquery and php,i think that is the problem

Comment: In what file is the javascript code located, an external `.js` file, an `.html` file or a `.php` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just trying to do something like thsi?

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content: '<ul><li><?php echo $deviceId; ?></li><li>Device configuration1</li><li>Device Description1</li></ul><a href="riacqua/activepanel.php">Goto RIACQUA</a>'
     });
```

That should do the trick, of course if your device id variable contains quotes/single quotes then you may have to strip them or escape them.

This should work no problem with a php file, but you may need to change other settings if you are trying to get this to render in another file type (html, htm, etc).

Comment: Glad I could help.  If you are running on an Apache server, you can usually use an .htaccess file to tell Apache to render PHP scripts for .htm and .html files too (or any file extension)

Answer (score 2):

```
content: '<ul><li><?=$deviceID?></li><li>Device configuration1</li><li>Device Description1</li></ul><a href="riacqua/activepanel.php">Goto RIACQUA</a>'
```